# Creating a generic makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

I'm trying to create a makefile which would have as little command repetition as possible. Basic idea is to have variable name assigned at the target, like so:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall

some_target:
    P = some_target

some_other_target:
    P = some_other_target
...
#common compilation command
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(P).c -o $(P).o
```

So there's only one compilation command which receives variable P which is unique for each target. Obviously example above doesn't work, what do i need to change to make it correct?

Answer (score 6):

This is already built in. The variable `$<` expands to the first dependency and `$^` expands to all dependencies. There is also `$?` which expands to only those dependencies which are newer than the target. See [the documentaion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for a full list.

Make already knows how to compile a `.c` file into an `.o` file, but if you want to see how it's done, the pattern looks a bit different from yours.

```
some_command.o: some_command.c
other.o: other.c
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@
```